# How can I modify Sencha Ext.form.HtmlEditor behavior?

Tags: extjs

I'm using sencha 3.4.
I'm trying to add functionality to the HtmlEditor buttons 
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.HtmlEditor

To be more specific:
I want to change the text direction with the text alignment buttons.
At the moment, those buttons are only changing the text alignment and not it's direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could achieve basic reverse with overriding `execCmd` method of [`Ext.form.HtmlEditor`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.HtmlEditor). But still i think it only takes one button for reversing the text (instead of both left and right justifiers).
Here's the [**FIDDLE**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2kut)

Comment: Thanks. Eventually, I've added two new buttons for this functionality.

Comment: Alright, marked it as the correct one because it shows how to override the button's behavior and this is basically what I was asking.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I've added two new buttons for this functionality.